# Going through a list to see how many consecutive letters are within a list Python

Tags: python-3.x, database, list, function

I am trying to run a function where it will recognize if 3 consecutive `b`s or `r`s are after one another within `list_` if it is I want the code to `print('divisible by 3')`.

```
list_ = ['b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'r']
if (list_%3==0):
     print('divisible by 3')
```

Comment: Just to confirm - what's your expected output given the sample input?  Can you show us where  you got stuck then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@firefireeyyy - do you know `itertools.groupby()` in Python?  I've change your `list_` variable to `lst`.

Then you can try this and figure out the answer next:

```py
from itertools import groupby
for k, gp in groupby(lst):
    print(k, list(gp))
```

Comment: Glad that it helps.  Check out other posts --- it seems that you have quite a few.